# How to get data from s3 to logstash?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logstash

In the logstash configuration file, I gave the following input plugin.

```
input{
  s3{
    bucket => 'bucket_name'
    region => 'eu-west-1'
  }
}
```

When I started logstash, it threw an error asking for AWS credentials. But I cannot provide AWS access_key_id and secret_key. I found that with IAM roles on EC2 instances, we shouldn't have to provide AWS credentials explicitly for an application that make those requests. I tried to understand how to configure IAM roles from [a logstash Github issue](http://github.com/elastic/logstash/issues/1778), but failed. Please suggest how I should configure logstash file so that I can get data from S3 without providing AWS credentials explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

When you are *creating* the EC2 instance, you may assign it an IAM role. If you don't give it a role when you create it, you cannot ever give it a role. You can modify the properties of a role (*e.g.* give the role more or less access) but you cannot change what role an instance has after the instance has been created.

The easiest way to test if an instance has the credentials you need is with the command-line tools:

```
$ echo $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
$
```

That shows that we don't have the environment variable set, so if we're getting credentials, they must be instance creds.

```
$ aws --region=eu-west-1 s3 ls my.bucket
                           PRE some-directory/
                           PRE another-dir/
2015-11-05 18:03:53        464 little-file
2014-10-28 15:32:13      19740 bigger-file.html
$
```

I was able to list the bucket contents, so the EC2 instance where I'm running this command must have an IAM role that allows it to list this bucket contents!

Comment: Ok, I'll create EC2 instance and assign an IAM role. MY doubt is if I have to specify anything more in the logstash file.Anyways, I'll first create and check as you suggested.Thans for ypur response.

Comment: It's not entirely clear to me which version of the s3 input plugin is available by default. However, the [most recent code](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-input-s3/blob/master/lib/logstash/inputs/s3.rb#L397) will behave correctly when given no credentials and run on a machine with a role. Make sure that your role has the correct permissions (the easiest thing is to do bad security and give it the "S3 Full Access" role).